# Completeness of space $\Lambda$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

While going through the following paper of Lorentz [link](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1103052109) titled "On theory of space $\Lambda$", I faced difficulty in the first theorem where he claims that the space $\Lambda$ is "complete" for $\phi$ decreasing. I don't understand how. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Lorentz refers to another paper [8] of him. Did you check this reference?

Comment: Yes, but that was not helpful. The weight function there was $\alpha x^{\alpha-1}$ for $\alpha \in (0,1)$ It's minimum value is 1 so we easily get cauchy's sequence in $L^1$ but in this case situation may be different.